# PhpStorm not recognizes a PHP class

Tags: php, phpstorm

this morning I faced with this issue and I don't know really how to solve this.

Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ampmj.png) and a video: http://screencast.com/t/2ubAbwPj6

P.S. When I refactor the file to "filename.PHP" PhpStorm detects it but if I change it back to "filename.php" PhpStorm won't detect it as a PHP file.

Comment: Have you saw this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4715669/711206

Comment: @Federico Thank you, that was the problem. http://screencast.com/t/Tqm94H9bSNe

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`
2. Locate `Text Files` entry there
3. Remove unwanted pattern from the bottom list (most likely will be `LoginListener` or `LoginListener.php`

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches...` -> `Invalidate and Restart`.

This will remove caches and indexes, the new caches will be built when the project is reopened.