# PhpStorm marks a single .phtml file as plain text

Tags: phpstorm

I have a problem similar to:

[Wrong syntax highlighting for PHP file in PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4306182/759866)

IIRC, I created a file under the wrong name (`IndexViewphtml`, no extension), then renamed it to `IndexView.phtml`. Since then, it is recognized as plain text:

[image]

As advised in the linked question, I went to `Settings|Editor|File Types` and ensured that this file name was not assigned to `Text` files:

[image: PhpStorm File Types]

I also checked that the file was not currently marked as plain text:

[image: PhpStorm mark as plain text]

As a last resort, I:

- deleted the `.phtml` file and its parent folder
- closed PhpStorm
- `rm -rf .idea`
- `rm -rf ~/.cache/JetBrains/PhpStorm*`

And to my surprise, **when I re-launch PhpStorm and recreate the folder + file, it is still recognized as plain text!**

If I rename it to, say `Index2.phtml`, the file is correctly recognized as PHP.

**What did I miss?** I'm using the latest 2020.3 EAP.

Comment: Weird. Try this: focus that file in Project View, then invoke `Ctrl+Q` (or whatever the shortcut you have for `View | Quick Documentation`) -- what so you see?

Comment: Have you checked whether `*.phtml`  is registered as a filetype for PHP files?

Comment: @NicoHaase It is, as I said if I rename to `Index2.phtml` it recognized as PHP (and so are my numerous other `.phtml` views).

Comment: @LazyOne Sorry, I rushed to find a solution and deleted the config directory, that I missed in my question, and it now works. I'm afraid I won't be able to debug further!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by deleting the config folder (I had missed this one):

```
rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm*
```

Obviously you restart PhpStorm from scratch at this stage (like a new install), but it's better for me than dealing with a PHP file as text.

Comment: Next time make a backup before deleting. Getting the actual reason / a way of resolving it without deleting everything will help others in the similar situation.

Comment: And yeah: PhpStorm, not PHPStorm 

Comment: Yeah sorry, next time I'll make a backup! As I said, I rushed for a solution... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't clear the whole config folder

Please check that your file type is not added in `Auto-detect file type by content` in File Type. If found remove and apply the changes.

**System > Preference > Editor > File Type > Auto-detect file type by content in File Type**

[image]